# Remove All Matches Except First One From String

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to remove all specific character matches except the first one from string.

**Example Code**

```py
specific_char = ','
example_str = '110,49144,35,123'
# Apply here magical one-liner.
print(example_str)  # '110,4914435123'
```

Thank you!

Comment: `new= example_str.split(specific_char)` , `new[0]+ specific_char+''.join(new[1:])`

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this

```
specific_char = ','
x = example_str.split(specific_char)
x[0]+specific_char+''.join(x[1:])
```

Answer (score -1):

Just for fun:

`example_str = example_str[::-1].replace(",", "", example_str.count(",")-1)[::-1]`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
c = ','
s = '110,49144,35,123'
result = ''.join(a for i, a in enumerate(s) if a != c or c not in s[:i])
```

Output:

```
'110,4914435123'
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's what you can do

```
specific_char = ','
example_str = '110,49144,35,123'
index = 0
for i in range(len(example_str)):
    if example_str[i] == specific_char:
        index = i
        break
example_str = example_str[:index+1]+example_str[index:].replace(specific_char,'')
```

Output

```
'110,4914435123'
```